# Concatenación de cadenas de caracteres en C

Tags: c, string, concatenación

Estoy tratando de ponerle un `.` por delante a una cadena de caracteres en *C*.

Para ello, estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
char* r1;
char* r2;

recogerString(&r2, MAX_RESP);
r1=(char*)malloc(strlen(r2+2)*sizeof(char*));

r1[0]='.';
strcat(r1,r2);
```

Método `RecogerString`:

```
void recogerString (char** punt_string, int max_long)
{
    char str[max_long];
    char str_sin_salto_linea[max_long];
    fgets(str, max_long, stdin);

    clear_if_needed(str);
    sscanf(str, "%s", str_sin_salto_linea); //eliminar el \n final

    (*punt_string) = (char *)malloc((strlen(str_sin_salto_linea)) * sizeof(char)); 
    strcpy((*punt_string), str_sin_salto_linea );     
}
```

El problema es que al hacer esto, en lugar de concatenar `.` a `r2` y guardarlo en `r1`, `r1` acaba siendo ***.<-un signo cambiante-r2***. ¿Cómo puedo asignarle únicamente el signo `.` a la primera posición de `r1` sin ninguno de estos signos? ¿Es necesario utilizar otra manera para referirse al carácter `.`?

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar el título a "concatenación de cadenas en C", pues el carácter `'.'` realmente es irrelevante aquí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que tener en `r1` una cadena correctamente formada, es decir, una secuencia de caracteres terminada en un byte de valor cero. Ese byte de valor 0 es el que le dice a `strcat()` (y al resto de funciones de manejo de cadenas) dónde termina esa cadena.

En tu caso has creado la cadena con `malloc()`, lo que te devuelve un puntero a una zona de memoria cuyo contenido no sabemos de antemano. Después pones un carácter `.` en la primera posición de esa zona, pero ¿qué hay en el resto? Es impredecible.

Cuando `strcat()` intente concatenar a la primera cadena, irá recorriendo ésta hasta encontrar un byte de valor 0 que le indica dónde termina, y entonces concatenará la otra a partir de esa posición. En tu caso, al no haber introducido explícitamente ese cero, es cuestión de suerte que tarde o temprano aparezca uno en la zona devuelta por `malloc()`. Todo lo que aparezca antes de ese cero se considera parte de `r1`. Es posible incluso que no aparezca ninguno en la zona reservada y siga mirando más allá, pudiendo ocasionar una violación de segmento.

Soluciones:

1. Pon el cero terminador, así: `r1[1]=0;`. (También puedes poner `r1[1]='\0'`, que es lo mismo, pero haciendo más claro que lo que estás metiendo es un carácter, el ASCII nulo)
2. Reserva la memoria con `calloc()` en lugar de `malloc()`. Esta función rellena con ceros la zona reservada antes de devolverte el puntero.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te complicas demasiado:

```
void recogerString( char** punt_string, int max ) {
  // Dejamos el punto ya puesto.
  char str[max_long] = '.'; 

  // Nos saltamos el punto.
  fgets( str + 1, max, stdin ); 

  // Quitamos el salto de línea.
  str[strlen( str ) - 1] = 0; 

  // Reservamos memoria.
  *punt_string = (char *)malloc( strlen( str ) );

  // Copiamos.
  strcpy( *punt_string, str );
}
```